# how to start Windows Logo test for my driver?

Tags: windows, driver, driver-signing, logo-testing

I am new in windows logo test . I heard this process from my friend . I created a application which consist of some drivers . so I need to sign from Microsoft for trusted installations of my software . I heard the windows logo process for sign my driver through some test conducted by me and need to send this report back to windows . So I have some doubt to setup this process . 
How to setup this process ? (how many system needed ? and which OS I should install for testing) and what are the requirements ?
I think there is a server and client machine (So 2 system is needed ?) . How to setup this system ? can you provide step by step tutorials ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The testing goes by a few names, WHQL, hardware certification, logo test, etc. Just to give a few more keys words to google.

Microsoft outlines the steps that you need to take https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh833792. Honestly, the process is not that bad all things considered:

- Buy a code signing certificate. Microsoft lists who they support and there are plenty of discussions on the OSR forums that discuss signing requirements in great detail. We use Digitcert and have no issue. I recommend reading up on this article to make your life easier: http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/. The whole cross-certificate detail is glossed over in the Microsoft docs.
- Setup your company in the hardware dashboard. Pretty straightforward here; just follow the directions for uploading your code cert. Sign all the legal stuff and setup any other developers on your team if they need access.
- Install the HCK. We bought the MSDN OS pack ($800 USD) just for the WHQL and it has been awesome. I used Server 2012 to run as the HCK server and installed it as a virtual machine on a pretty beefy PC. Runs great, no problems installing it, and configuration is intuitive. More details are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/jj123537.aspx
- Configure your test PCs. I used a mix of VMs and physical PCs for this part. Going through the provisioning process is automated for the most part. I recommend taking VM snapshots once completed in case something goes south during testing.
- The HCK server walks you through the tests you need to perform depending on the type of driver you are testing. For example, we are working on a printer so all of our testing involved printing.
- We tested against XP SP3 all the way through Windows 8.1, both 32 and 64 bit though your needs may differ. We needed the driver in Windows update, not necessarily the hardware logo. Once completed we simply uploaded the passing report through the hardware dashboard and that was that.

It seems like a huge task but it is not the worst thing in the world so keep at it you will get it done!